# if $\forall x\forall y[P(x) \land P(y) \implies Q(x,y)]$ then prove that $\forall y \exists x[P(x)\land \lnot Q(x,y) \implies \lnot P(y)]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I was solving a past paper for my first discrete math course in preparation for my first discrete math exam and I found this question and I had absolutely no idea what to do.

Comment: What proof system are you using ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I haven't tried anything. I thought I might try using any of the rules of inference for quantified statements but then I didn't see myself going anywhere, so I stopped.
I do not know what a proof system is. My course included only one chapter of propositional logic (the first chapter in Kenneth Rosen's book)

Comment: With only propositional logic you acnnot prove it; you need rules for quantifiers. See Rosen Ch.1.4 Predicates and Quantifiers and Ch.1.6 Rules of Inference. More specifically, see page 76: Rules of Inference for Quantified Statements.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I studied the whole chapter I know all of these rules I just didn't know what "proof system" mean.

Comment: If this is for a discrete math class, then any informal proof is probably fine.  You probably don't actually need any specific proof system.  Try drawing a picture of a table, with Px along the top, Py along the left, and Qxy being inside the table at the intersection of Px and Py.  In terms of the picture, figure out what the statements are saying.

Comment: For this problem, consider what happens at the points when $y = x$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

With [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) it is quite easy.

With Rosen's proof system the proof is a little bit tricky.

*Proof sketch*:

Remove the leading quantifiers using Universal instantiation (page 76) to get:

> $(P(x) ∧ P(y)) \to Q(x,y)$.

The apply the rule: "replace the  conditional statement $p → q$ with the equivalent disjunction ¬$p ∨ q$ (page 74: resolution)" and use De Morgan to get:

> $\lnot P(x) \lor \lnot P(y) \lor Q(x,y)$.

Now rewrite it as:

> $\lnot P(x) \lor Q(x,y) \lor \lnot P(y)$

and use De Morgan and the equivalence above again to get:

> > $(P(x) \land \lnot Q(x,y)) \to \lnot P(y)$.

Now use Existential generalization followed by Universal generalization (page 76) to get:

> $∀y∃x[(P(x) ∧ ¬Q(x,y)) \to ¬P(y)]$.

---

You can consider also onother possible "propositional transformation": $(p_1 \land p_2) \to q$ is equivalent to $p_1 \to (p_2 \to q)$ and $(p_2 \to q)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot q \to \lnot p_2)$.

Thus, we have that $(p_1 \land p_2) \to q$ is equivalent to: $(p_1 \land \lnot q) \to \lnot p_2$.

Comment: How did that $\forall x$ become a $\exists x$? The text doesn't introduce us to any of the inference rules done on more than one quantifier so I don't know.

Comment: Weakening.  In any *non-empty* domain, $\forall x~R(x)$ implies $\exists x~R(x)$.

Comment: @EyadH. - not needed; we use rule of Existential generalization (page 76).